# Unable to locate id/name/xpath locator in selenium

Tags: selenium

I am facing below exception when trying to enter email in edit box of instagram website. Please help. Same issue when trying to locate element using "name","id" attribute.

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //input[@name='emailOrPhone']

```
package selfirst;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Openbrowser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\samiuddin\\codezilla\\workspaces\\sel\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.instagram.com");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='emailOrPhone']")).sendKeys("rahulreddy.olay@gmail.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems fine...you have to use "name", "xpath" selector here as id is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

The Xpath looks wrong as per what I observed from Instagram website.

Use:

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='username']")).sendKeys("rahulreddy.olay@gmail.com");
```

Comment: Tried, still the same issue.

Comment: package selfirst;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Openbrowser {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\samiuddin\\codezilla\\workspaces\\sel\\geckodriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("http://www.instagram.com");
  System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='username']")).sendKeys("rahulreddy.olay@gmail.com");
 }
}

Comment: Superb! It worked. But how? Can you please explain a bit.

Comment: The line `driver.findelement` was been executed when the website and its webelements was not properly loaded, hence resulting in `NoSuchElementException`. And by applying wait statement, we are waiting for the website to be loaded properly before executing the next line. Kindly mark the answer as Accepted if it solved your Issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you are seeing **org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException** is because of two reasons :

- The *xpath* which you have used doesn't identifies the  *Phone number* / *username* / *email* field uniquely as `@name='emailOrPhone'` is not an attribute of the intended field. You can use the below line of code :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='username']")).sendKeys("rahulreddy.olay@gmail.com");
  ```

But it seems the *website* is based on *ReactJS* so you have to induce `WebDriverWait` for the intended field to be rendered with in the *HTML DOM* as follows :

```
WebElement username = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@name='username']")));
username.sendKeys("rahulreddy.olay@gmail.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the implicit wait after launch the browser

```
driver.get("http://www.instagram.com");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code you can use :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,5000); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("emailOrPhone")));
WebElement input=driver.findElement(By.name("emailOrPhone"));
input.click();
input.sendKeys("rahulreddy.olay@gmail.com");
```